# How is redisAsyncConnect() different from redisConnect()?

Tags: c, redis, hiredis

In what cases should redisAsyncConnect be used, instead of redisConnect? What is the difference in implementation of both functions?

Answer (score 1):

redisConnect uses synchronous or blocking socket IO.  redisAsyncConnect uses asynchronous or non-blocking IO.

If you need further explanation, then you need an education in network communications, beyond the scope of this answer!

The difference in implementation of both functions can be found on github:

https://github.com/redis/hiredis